# Hourly Repeating Alarm on user selected week days

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm, repeatingalarm

I am making a reminder app where the **user sets** an interval for notification reminders. The user sets the **hourly interval** and then the **daily interval**.

For example the user wants to get **notified every 3 hours** on **Mondays**, **Tuesdays** and **Saturdays**.

I'm using this method to send notifications hourly:

```
private void scheduleNotification(String notificationTitle, int notificationID, int hours, int minutes) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationPanelReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("title", notificationTitle);
        intent.putExtra("notificationID", notificationID);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            mContext
            , notificationID
            , intent
            , PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        long repeatInterval = (minutes * 60 * 1000) + (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
           manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP
                , SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + repeatInterval
                , repeatInterval
                , pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

So I need **this interval** to **repeat weekly** on user selected days

Does anyone know how I can make that work?

Comment: `I already know how ...` you should show here, what you have so far.

Comment: @PeterMmm I added the method I'm using for the interval I need it repeated weekly

Comment: I'm not a `AlarmManager` user, but I can see method `setExact()`. I would calc a list of date/time instances (eg. starting at 00:00 each 3h on next Monday, starting at 00:00 each 3h on next Tuesday, etc) and schedule each with `setExact()`.

Comment: @PeterMmm Thank you for your response Peter. I'll try to make it that way you suggested. If this works I will respond with the solution.